# myOpenID - The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match

Tags: support, openid, login, myopenid

When trying to log in for the first time to http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com using myOpenID openid I got the following error:

```
The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match. Assertion endpoint info: ClaimedIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderEndpoint: https://www.myopenid.com/server OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: Discovered endpoint info: [{ ClaimedIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderEndpoint: http://www.myopenid.com/server OpenID version: 2.0 Service Type URIs: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1 http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/phishing-resistant http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0 }, { ClaimedIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderEndpoint: http://www.myopenid.com/server OpenID version: 1.1 Service Type URIs: http://openid.net/signon/1.1 http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1 http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/phishing-resistant http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0 }, { ClaimedIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderLocalIdentifier: http://piotr.openid.dobrogost.pl/ ProviderEndpoint: http://www.myopenid.com/server OpenID version: 1.0 Service Type URIs: http://openid.net/signon/1.0 http://openid.net/sreg/1.0 http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1 http://schemas.openid.net/pape/policies/2007/06/phishing-resistant http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0 },]
```

I had the same problem logging into SO in the past - see my comment to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55878/stack-overflow-and-steam-community-openids/55923#55923) answer.

What's wrong?

Comment: There is another [recent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113986/myopenid-login-no-longer-working) encounter as well.