# MyOpenId Login no longer working

Tags: support, myopenid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [myOpenID - The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106330/myopenid-the-openid-provider-issued-an-assertion-for-an-identifier-whose-disco)

I am normally this user: https://stackoverflow.com/users/330772/sam-phillips

But I can no longer login using my openid (http://openid.samdanavia.com/sam), as it gives the "The OpenID Provider issued an assertion for an Identifier whose discovery information did not match." error. The OpenID provider is MyOpenId.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: I just checked your account, and the OpenID you listed is associated. May not be _our_ bug, though.

Comment: Eeek! 'Tis a dupe indeed. Sorry for the editorial 'noise' :)

Comment: Note that since you use a delegated OpenId, you can change the provider on your server to one that works.